# Trying to get count of childs rows

Tags: postgresql, count, sum

I'm trying to get the count of child of a parent row. The sql query I'm using as follow only pulls the immediate count, how can I get total count as childs can have more childs.

```
select  c.id, c.base32_id, c.author, c.message, c.title, c.type, c.datetime,
(select count(*) from comment where parent_id= c.id ) as ChildCount
from comment c where c.parent_id is null order by id asc limit 25
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first retrieve the whole tree of comments using a [recursive common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html). Then you can count the number of children for each root node:

```
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id
   from comment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id
   from comment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select root_id, count(*) as comment_count
from all_comments
group by root_id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea/15

If you don't want to get the count per "thread" but for each node, you can use something like this:

```
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id, 1 as level
   from comment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id, p.level + 1
   from comment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select ac.id, 
       ac.parent_id,
       ac.root_id,
       count(*) over (partition by ac.root_id) - count(*) over (partition by ac.root_id order by level) as child_count
from all_comments ac
order by ac.id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea/17

The above is using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to calculate the total number or nodes for a root node and the number of nodes in each level:

`count(*) over (partition by ac.root_id)` counts the number of children (including the root) for each root node.

`count(*) over (partition by ac.root_id order by level)` counts the number of nodes *up to* the current's node level. The difference between the total count and the ones "till now" is the number of child nodes.

---

Btw: `comment` is a SQL keyword, you shouldn't use it as a table name.

Comment: Thank you that works! One question for the first query how would I put columns from the parent, such as 'title'?

Answer (score 0):

I not see exact what you will achieve, but here is a try:

```
select  parent_id , count(id) as comment from comment
group by parent_id
order by parent_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea/14