# Optimal query pattern to count related entries in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Assume I have the following table schema and data

```
create table categories(
    id integer primary key,
    parent_id integer
);

insert into categories
values
    (1,0),
    (2,0),
    (3,1),
    (4,1);
```

I need to count the number of children for each entry, i.e. the result should be

```
 id | parent_id | count
----+-----------+-------
  1 |         0 |     2
  2 |         0 |     0
  3 |         1 |     0
  4 |         1 |     0
```

The following query produces the correct result but I'm worried about the performance. I guess that it loops through the table as many time as there are rows in it.

```
select *, (select count(*) from categories b where a.id=b.parent_id) from categories a
```

It is possible to optimize it?

Comment: Duplicate [Trying to get count of childs rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110486/trying-to-get-count-of-childs-rows)

Comment: The link does provide an alternative solution but doesn't give any input on performance which is being questioned here.

Comment: @mustaccio This link shows how to get a total count including the children's kids etc, with a Recursive CTE which is allot more complicate than a simple count.  It does not apply, and would preform very well on lots of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested selects  can be slower or be faster depends on how many records are being processed.

```
select *, (select count(*) from categories b where a.id=b.parent_id) 
   from categories a
```

This can be faster or have the same speed if only a few records or with where clause filters this down

```
select *, (select count(*) from categories b where a.id=b.parent_id) 
   from categories a  where a.id = 5
```

A faster solution for all the records would be something like this

```
Select categories.*, coalesce(counted, 0) from categories 
   left join ( select parent_id, count(*) as counted from categories group by parent_id) child
   on categories.id = child.parent_id
```

with this query  planner has an easier time figuring out what to do.  Nested selects the planner has harder time with as it has to treat them as VOLATILE.  meaning it has to keep calling the nested query for each record

Comment: it gives `null` intead of `0` for entries without children

Comment: change to count(*)

Comment: it makes no difference

Comment: this should fix it

Comment: now it works perfect. thank you!